# d3js - How to update an existing svg path in a simple d3 line chart with new data flowing through?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dynamic, charts

beginner to d3 here having some fun learning but a bit stuck. I am trying to create a simple chart that will plot a line for some raw price data in the format of (x being date, y being value) and an average line. I have got the code working so that I can create a line on an svg for set of static data.

Now what I am trying to do is update the data set with a new stream of data and I want the existing line to extend as i want to plot a series of data so need the old data there too.

Can anyone please help me find a way to do this? Is this possible without deleting the old line and re drawing? I.e I want it to extend. Can it be achieved using enter update exit pattern? Alot of the examples I have seen for this pattern always add/remove new shapes rather than joining/extending if that makes sense.

I've created a d3 simple line chart which displays a line for static data, but when i use setInterval to ping some new data, rather than extending the line, it adds a new one.

Eventually the chart will have multiple lines which will all need updating depending on the data being fed through

```js
<script>
        
                var data_set = [
                    { 'Date': '2009-03-23', 'Raw': 25, 'Raw2': 25, 'Asset': 'A' },
                    { 'Date': '2009-03-24', 'Raw': 28, 'Raw2': 25.4, 'Asset': 'A' },
                    { 'Date': '2009-03-25', 'Raw': 26, 'Raw2': 25.37, 'Asset': 'A' },
                    { 'Date': '2009-03-26', 'Raw': 22, 'Raw2': 25.03, 'Asset': 'A' },
                    { 'Date': '2009-03-27', 'Raw': 19, 'Raw2': 24.42, 'Asset': 'A' },
                    { 'Date': '2009-03-28', 'Raw': 23, 'Raw2': 24.28, 'Asset': 'A' }]

                // All of these vars have nothing to do with data yet - it's all setup code
                var margin = { top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
                var svgWidth = 1200;
                var svgHeight = 1000;
                var graphWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
                var graphHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                // var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y");
                var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
                
                
                var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, graphWidth]);
                var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([graphHeight, 0]);
                var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10); // for colours
                var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x).ticks(10);
                var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(10);

                // Need to create the lines manually for each bit of data
                var line1 = d3.line()
                    .x(function (d) { return x(d.Date); })
                    .y(function (d) { return y(d.Raw); });
                var line2 = d3.line()
                    .x(function (d) { return x(d.Date); })
                    .y(function (d) { return y(d.Raw2); });

                // Creates the SVG area within the div on the dom 
                // Just doing this once 
                var svg = d3.select("#graphDiv")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", svgWidth)
                    .attr("height", svgHeight)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform",
                        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                     .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                         svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
                     }));


                    // Add the X Axis
                    svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + graphHeight + ")")
                        .call(xAxis);
                    // Text label for x axis 
                    svg.append("text")
                        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text("timeseries dates")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (graphWidth / 2) + " ," + (graphHeight + margin.top) + ")");

                    // Add the Y Axis
                    svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "y axis")
                        .call(yAxis);
                    // text label for the y axis
                    svg.append("text")
                        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
                        .attr("x", 0 - (graphHeight / 2))
                        .attr("dy", "1em")
                        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text("price points");

                
                function drawGraph(data_set) {
                    // Pass in the data here 
                    data_set.forEach(function (d) {
                        d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
                        // + converts the strings to numbers from dataset
                        d.Raw = +d.Raw;
                        d.EWMA = +d.Raw2;
                    });
                    // Domains here represent the complete set of valaues e.g all dates
                    // These are set based on loaded data 
                    x.domain(d3.extent(data_set, function (d) { return d.Date; }));
                    y.domain([d3.min(data_set, function (d) { return Math.min(d.Raw, d.Raw2) }),
                    d3.max(data_set, function (d) { return Math.max(d.Raw, d.Raw2) })]
                    );
                    
                    var lines = svg.selectAll("path").data(data_set)
                     lines.enter().append("path")
                          .attr("class", "dataLine1")
                          .style("stroke", "pink")
                          .style("fill", "none").attr("d", line1(data_set))
                     lines.enter().append("path")
                          .attr("class", "dataLine2")
                          .style("stroke", "#21e0f4").attr("d",line2(data_set));
                    // // Remove any existing ones
                    lines.exit().remove()
                    
                }
                // display initial chart
                window.onload = drawGraph(data_set)
                // Push new data every 5 seconds for a specific date
                var h = setInterval(function () {
                     data_set.push({ 'Date': '2009-03-29', 'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), 'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25), 'Asset': 'A' }
                    ,{ 'Date': '2009-03-30', 'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), 'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25), 'Asset': 'A' },
                    { 'Date': '2009-03-31', 'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), 'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25), 'Asset': 'A' },
                    { 'Date': '2009-04-01', 'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), 'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25), 'Asset': 'A' },
                    { 'Date': '2009-04-02', 'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), 'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25), 'Asset': 'A' },
                    { 'Date': '2009-04-03', 'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), 'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25), 'Asset': 'A' });                    console.log('pushing');
                    drawGraph(data_set);
                    clearInterval(h); //doing this so that it doesnt spam - if i uncomment this, it will keep spamming new lines
                }, 5000);
            </script>
```

I am expecting there to be two lines, one for the raw value and one for the raw2 value. After 5 seconds I push some new data and expect to see both lines extended.

Currently what happens is two new lines are drawn for the new data(raw value  and raw value2) whereas I would like the existing ones to be extended.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data_set = [{
    'Date': '2009-03-23',
    'Raw': 25,
    'Raw2': 25,
    'Asset': 'A'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-24',
    'Raw': 28,
    'Raw2': 25.4,
    'Asset': 'A'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-25',
    'Raw': 26,
    'Raw2': 25.37,
    'Asset': 'A'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-26',
    'Raw': 22,
    'Raw2': 25.03,
    'Asset': 'A'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-27',
    'Raw': 19,
    'Raw2': 24.42,
    'Asset': 'A'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-28',
    'Raw': 23,
    'Raw2': 24.28,
    'Asset': 'A'
  }
]


var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};
var svgWidth = 600;
var svgHeight = 1000;
var graphWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var graphHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y");
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, graphWidth]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([graphHeight, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10); // for colours
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x).ticks(10);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(10);

// Need to create the lines manually for each bit of data
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  });

// Creates the SVG area within the div on the dom 
// Just doing this once 
var svg = d3.select("#graphDiv")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight)
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
  }));

// Add the X Axis
g.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + graphHeight + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
// Text label for x axis 
g.append("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("timeseries dates")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (graphWidth / 2) + " ," + (graphHeight + margin.top) + ")");

// Add the Y Axis
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
// text label for the y axis
g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x", 0 - (graphHeight / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("price points");


function drawGraph(data_set) {

  let pathData = []
  //assume 2 paths
  pathData.push([])
  pathData.push([])

  // Pass in the data here 
  data_set.forEach(function(d) {

    let path0 = {}
    let path1 = {}

    path0.date = parseDate(d.Date)
    path1.date = parseDate(d.Date)

    path0.y = +d.Raw
    path1.y = +d.Raw2

    pathData[0].push(path0)
    pathData[1].push(path1)

  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data_set, function(d) {
    return parseDate(d.Date);
  }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(data_set, function(d) {
      return Math.min(d.Raw, d.Raw2)
    }),
    d3.max(data_set, function(d) {
      return Math.max(d.Raw, d.Raw2)
    })
  ]);

  var lines = g.selectAll(".path")
    .data(pathData)

  lines.exit().remove()

  var enter = lines.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "path")
    .style("stroke", (d, i) => z(i))

  var merge = enter.merge(lines)
    .attr("d", line)



}
// display initial chart
window.onload = drawGraph(data_set)
// Push new data every 5 seconds for a specific date
var h = setInterval(function() {
  data_set.push({
    'Date': '2009-03-29',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-03-30',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-03-31',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-04-01',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-04-02',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-04-03',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  });
  drawGraph(data_set);
  clearInterval(h); //doing this so that it doesnt spam - if i uncomment this, it will keep spamming new lines
}, 5000); >
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graphDiv"></div>
```

There are few issues with your current code that need addressing:

1. To create 2 lines based on data, it would be best for the array to contain 2 elements, each with its own array of data points. This will allow the line function to work as intended and be resuable across each line you want to create. In the example below, I create a new dataset ('pathData') to achieve this.
2. The enter/update/merge pattern needs to updating so that you only create the lines once, and thereafter just update the path ('d' attr) when new data arrives

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Would you be able to advise how to get this going for basically groups of data? So if some of the data was a different asset, each one would have its own line and values. Cheers @TomShanley